# How to upload video in node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to upload video in node js and i have some doubts related.Is image upload and video upload are same i.e the code for image upload work for video upload?

Here is my code,

```
exports.uploadVideo = function( req, res ) {
    upload_image = '';
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
            res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
            return;
        }
        var obj = req.body;
        obj.video = upload_image;
        if(obj.edit){
            delete obj.edit;
            updateBlog(req, res, obj, 'update');
        } else {console.log('hi')
            addVideo(req, res, obj);
        }
    });
};

    var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, config.videoUploadPath);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        var ext = '';
        var name = '';
        if(file.originalname){
            var p = file.originalname.lastIndexOf(".");
            ext = file.originalname.substring(p+1);
            var firstName = file.originalname.substring(0, p+1);
            name = firstName + '-' + Date.now();
            name += '.'+ext;
        }
        upload_image += name;
        upload_image += ',';
        upload_image  = upload_image.replace(' ', '');
        callback(null, name);
    }
   });
     var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).array('video');
```

According to my routes,exports.uploadVideo() is called first.I am completely new to this,can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Image and video uploads are same, because ultimately they are `multipart` form data. What is the issue you are facing in the above mentioned code ?

Comment: Hi Mukesh,it says the error file entity is too large when i upload it from postman.What should be the contenet type for file upload?

Comment: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: still it is saying  file size is too large.

Comment: Are you getting `413` error ? Also, you are using `nginx` at server

Comment: I am getting this error when i uploaded from client-side.

Comment: This is my error   TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined